# its not uploading more than 2 files at same time in react filepond?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filepond

I want to send more than 100 files simultaneously but in network call I can see that only 2 files uploading at same time , so my whole upload is getting slower , is there any option to change that upload count to minimum 20 at a time ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: consider adding `reactjs` and `javascript` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to me . I found answer for this

we can use maxParallelUploads={20} in filepond .

```
<FilePond
          allowMultiple={true}
          server={server(projId, reqId)}
          instantUpload={true}
          ref={pond}
          files={files}
          maxParallelUploads={20}
          onaddfile={onAddFile}
          labelFileProcessing='Your files are uploading'
          onremovefile={onRemoveFile}
          onprocessfile={onProcessFile}
          allowRevert={false}
          labelIdle={label}
        />
```